# java date parse exception while conveting UTC to local time zone

Tags: java, java-time

I get a UTC date with following format and how can convert this UTC date to my local time zone?

my input date is `2015-03-17 06:00:00 +0000` and I tried the following coding its gives parsing exception.

My code:

```
DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss 'Z'");
utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = utcFormat.parse("2015-03-17 06:00:00 +0000"); // java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
System.out.println(utcFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two mistakes in your code.

1. As others already mentioned you have additional `'` in your pattern around `Z`.
2. You specify the pattern as `dd-MM-yyyy` but try to parse the date as `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Correct version:

```
DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = utcFormat.parse("2015-03-17 06:00:00 +0000");
utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
System.out.println(utcFormat.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to the quotes in the date pattern.

Try this...

```
DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove ' surrounding Z and try again.

Comment: That will not be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I should like to contribute the modern answer. The `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes used in the question are long outdated, and today we have so much better. I recommend the modern Java date and time API known as JSR-310 or `java.time`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2015-03-17 06:00:00 +0000", formatter)
            .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .format(formatter));
```

On my computer in the Europe/Copenhagen time zone this prints

```
2015-03-17 07:00:00 +0100
```

Using `ZoneId.systemDefault()` is fragile, though, since any program running on the JVM can change its default time zone and thereby alter the behaviour of the above snippet. If you can, it’s better to use a time zone ID in the *region/city* format, for example `ZoneId.of("Asia/Tomsk")` or `ZoneId.of("America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos")`.

**Question: Can I use the modern API with my Java version?**

If using at least Java **6**, you can.

- In Java 8 and later the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get [the ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of the new classes (that’s ThreeTen for JSR-310, where the modern API was first defined).
- On Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP, and I think that there’s a wonderful explanation in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 0):

This function is tested and works perfectly with any java.util.Date object.

```
private SimpleDateFormat getDateFormat() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = (SimpleDateFormat) SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.SHORT, SimpleDateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.getDefault());
    String pattern = dateFormat.toLocalizedPattern();
    pattern = pattern.trim();
    dateFormat.applyLocalizedPattern(pattern);
    return dateFormat;
}

//And here is the usage
SimpleDateFormat sdf = getDateFormat();
sdf.format(new Date());
```

I refactored the code from the following web site which you may find of great use for formatting to different types of java.util.Date objects:

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=java.text.SimpleDateFormat&method=applyLocalizedPattern

Hope this helps